# Implementing strcat() using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am reading K&R and trying to do the excercise involving writing a version of strcat (attach one string to the end of the other) using pointers. This is what I have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void mystrcat(char *s,char *t)
{
    while(*s++);
    *s--;
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}

int main()
{
    int size = 1024;
    char *s1, *s2;
    s1 = malloc(size);
    s2 = malloc(size);
    s1 = "Hello ";
    s2 = "World";
    mystrcat(s1,s2);
    printf("%s",s1);
    return 0;
}
```

The program runs but crashes straight away, not very experienced with pointers so can't work out the error.

Comment: Use `s--` instead of `*s--`.

Comment: Does K&R use `malloc` there already? Which exercise is it? Should be pointer chapter...

Comment: Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `malloc()` to assure the operation was successful.   Then pass those pointers to `free()` before exiting the program.

Comment: regarding lines like: `s1 = "Hello ";`.   This overlays the pointer returned from malloc with the ptr to "Hello ", thereby forever losing the original pointer, resulting in a memory leak.  Suggest: `char * ptr = "Hello "; for( int i=0;  *ptr[i]; i++ ) { s1[i] = ptr[i]; } s1[i] = '\0';   There is no need to malloc the s2, as that array will not be changing.  Instead say: `s2 = "World";

Comment: I would replace these two lines: `while(*s++);
    *s--;` with: `for( ; *s; s++ );`  then no need for corrections to the 's' pointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
s1 = malloc(size);
s2 = malloc(size);
s1 = "Hello ";
s2 = "World";
```

You have allocated space for `s1` and `s2`, but instead of using it, you are making them point to string literals. These string literals are stored in a non-writable place of the memory (i.e., you should not mess with it).

In short, you have to change your code to:

```
s1 = malloc(size);
s2 = malloc(size);
strcpy( s1, "Hello " );
strcpy( s2, "World" );
```

Now you are using the allocated space.
Hope this helps.

EDITED: you also have a problem here:

```
void mystrcat(char *s,char *t)
{
    while(*s++);
    *s--;
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```

The second line should be `s--`, instead of `*s--`. `*s--` would decrease the pointer `s` and access that new position. You don't actually need to dereference the pointer just to decrease it. You just want the pointer to point to a position before it is pointing to now. That's simply `s--`.

Comment: The first (and most prominently presented) is not the reason for the crash, but for a memory leak (only).

Comment: `*s--` does not decrement a `char`, it decrements the pointer.  But it does dereference a pointer likely to be outside an array bound (and then discard that value).

Comment: In a PC, yes, it is probable that it won't crash. But that does not mean it is correct. That's the famous undefined behaviour. It could potentially make the program crash in your PC, even if it does not do it. Now imagine a program compiled for a Gameboy Advance. The literals would be stored with the code in the cartridge (read-only memory), and it would certainly crash, 100%.

Answer (score 2):

You made another mistake in `*s--`. Pointer `s` is out of the buffer, and you shouldn't dereference it.

```
void mystrcat(char *s,char *t)
{
    while(*s++);
    s--;
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory for the strings, but then overrides it and lose the reference to this memory:

```
// allocate memory
s1 = malloc(size);
s2 = malloc(size);
// assign another address, e.g. lose the pointer
s1 = "Hello ";
s2 = "World";
```

You should copy the string to the allocate memory:

```
// allocate memory
s1 = malloc(size);
s2 = malloc(size);
// copy the string into it
strcpy(s1, "Hello ");
strcpy(s2, "World");
```

Also, it is a good practice to always [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) the memory you allocate after you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
s1 = "Hello ";
```

Now `s1` is pointing at a read-only array of 7 characters storing the literal "Hello ".  You've lost the pointer to the allocated 1024 characters that `s1` was pointing at before.  So your attempt to append to `s1` is illegal.

Try maybe `strcpy(s1, "Hello ");` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy a string by simple assignment.

If you want to copy "Hello " into a memory allocated with malloc, you need to copy the string into that block of memory:

```
s1 = malloc(size);
s2 = malloc(size);
strcpy(s1, "Hello ");
strcpy(s2, "World");
```

Direct assignment doesn't work with arrays.

"Hello " is essentially a char array.

Also, like someone said in the comments, "Hello " is allocated in a read only section of the code (Since it's allocated during compile time), so when you used your assignment, you actually redirect s1 to a read-only location, and when you try to write in a read only location, you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the function would look better if to define it the following way

```
char * mystrcat( char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    char *p = s1;

    while( *s1 ) ++s1;
    while( *s1++ = *s2++ );

    return p;
}
```

The standard C function `strcat` returns pointer to the destination string.

As for the `main` then there are memory leaks because at first `s1` and `s2` are set to the addreses of the allocated memory and then they are are reassigned by the addresses of first characters of the string literals.

And moreover string literals in C and C++ are immutable. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour of the program.

You could write instead

```
int size = 1024;
char *s;

s = malloc(size);
s[0] = '\0';

mystrcat( s, "Hello " );
mystrcat( s, "World" );

printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );
```

Or even you could write in one line

```
printf( "\"%s\"\n", mystrcat( mystrcat( s, "Hello " ), "World" ) );
```